# Using X11 in XCode

Tags: c, xcode, x11

In my Xcode project, I want to use X11 framework. X11 is installed on my computer since when I add `-L/usr/X11R6/lib` to my makefile, my program runs without problems.

How can I link X11 framework to XCode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no X11 *framework* - you just need to add the relevant headers and libraries to your project and Xcode will do the right thing.

Comment: You can just drag libraries to your project in the same way that you drag headers and source files. Tip: drag the whole /usr/X11R6/lib directory to your project and then remove any libraries that you don't need. Ditto for the headers.

Comment: Note that before lion however, X11 was an optional install, and might not be there if you distribute the app. Actually I'm not sure if it's still optional for Lion, but it's been on by default since Leopard anyway.

Comment: @Per: good point - I don't think there are static versions of the libraries either